# Subscribe to firestore from React.useEffect using two queries (async operation)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I have three collections in a firestore database: users, customers and nodes. And example of the properties of interest of their documents is:

User (Document name: IDUSER)

```json
{
...<Non interesting properties>,
customer: ref = customers/IDCUSTOMER
}
```

Customer (Document name: IDCUSTOMER)

```json
{
...<Non interesting properties>
}
```

Node (Document name: IDNODE)

```json
{
...<Non interesting properties>,
customer: ref = customers/IDCUSTOMER
}
```

With this configuration, I want to group users by their assigned customer (one customer can have multiple users) and use this customer assigned to provide access to the nodes assigned to the given customer. Thus, all users from a customer can view the customer's nodes. I don't have problems with this configuration.

My problem is that in a ReactJS application (+Typescript), I want to subscribe a given component to the nodes collection in order to get new added nodes. For this, I need to:

1. Generate a query (`q1`) to get the customer assigned to the current user.
2. Get data from `q1` (an `async` function).
3. Generate a query (`q2`) to get the customer's nodes (this query depends on the data received from step 2).
4. Execute the `onSnapshot` function, and return the `unsubscribe` function to the `React.useEffect` hook in order to execute it when the component is dismounted.

My problem is that the flow depends on an `async` function, the final `unsubscribe` function is a `Promise<Unsubscribe>` function and it throws error.

I know that to use `async` in `React.useEffect` is a bad idea.

How can I implement this???

Thank you very much in advance for your time.